# Calling an npm package from a python subprocess on windows fails

Tags: python, node.js

I'm wanting to automate production of some topojson files and have tried various permutations of subprocess. `Popen,.communicate()` and `check_output()` with no success.

The response from windows is

> '*topojson*' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In fact calling any installed npm package results in a similar response.
Opening a command prompt and then typing in the same command runs perfectly well.

I’ve tried (in desperation) using Popen and to create a command shell and writing to stdin, but with no success.
It should be as easy as:

```
topocmd = "topojson -o \"D:\polygons.json\" --id-property GLUID -- \"D:\VoronoiClipped_WSG84.shp\""
result = check_output(topocmd, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Is it possible to call nodejs packages like this on Windows, or am I missing something?

Comment: try not calling `topojson` but give it a full path to your node installation and then let node call topojson.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to add an example. Do you mean something along the lines of:  "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" topojson -o "D:\polygons.json" --id-property GLUID -- "D:\VoronoiClipped_WSG84.shp"

Comment: yes. something like `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\patho\to\topojson.js" -o "D:\polygons.json" --id-property GLUID -- "D:\VoronoiClipped_WSG84.shp" `

Comment: Lovely, thanks@k_nut. This works (though it's not pretty and I'll revert back to an args list):      `node = "\"c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe\""
topojs = "\"C:\\Users\\Simon\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\topojson\\bin\\topojson\""
args = "-o \"D:\polygons.json\" --id-property GLUID -- \"D:\VoronoiClipped_WSG84.shp\""
result2 = check_output(node + " " + topojs + " " + args, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)`